# '90s movie about teens trapped in a haunted mansion or museum

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I am trying to find the title of a movie I watched about a group of teens trapped in a haunted mansion or museum.

- The movie is a late '90s movie. It is about a group of teens in medieval costumes trapped and isolated in a haunted mansion or museum.
- The group of teens notice the mansion is suddenly empty and they try to escape the mansion, but they can't.
- The teens each experience hallucinations. One teen girl looks into the mirror and sees her beaten face. She thinks she has been abused by her boyfriend until she finds out is was just an hallucination.
- I think the teens' hallucinations are based on their weaknesses and insecurities. I think the mansion is haunted by evil spirits.
- One teen boy gets killed by an evil spirit disguised as himself. The boy gets put in a book and labeled for dying of suicide.
- The movie is in English and made in U.S. The characters are a teen boy dressed in a '20s costume and another teen boy in a medieval costume. A girl with long curly hair in a black dress with a cloak. Another girl with blonde hair in a medieval costume. Plus, a teen boy wearing a newspaper man '20s costume.

Sorry, I did not get to see the end of this movie, but I would be happy if you could tell me the name of it.

Comment: On what media did you watch it (streaming, DVD or bluray, TV or in a cinema)? In what country did you watch it (not all films will be released worldwide)?

Comment: I watched this movie on TV in the U.S.

Comment: @Jaimie - In roughly which year did you watch it, and how do you know it's a late '90s movie?

Comment: I watched this movie this year (2021). I knew it was a late 90's movie because of the movie quality, the actors, the outfits, and the culture. Maybe the movie was an early 2000's movie.

Comment: Jamie, did you find out? Oddly enough, I think i know exactly what movie your talking about and I have been trying to find out the name recently. At one point does someone have an old helmet on and there head gets squeezed? If so we are.

Comment: @ROB - The correct answer to this question is likely _The Club_, as proposed in [one of the answers below](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/260942/122024); it matches all the details listed in the question. If that's not the movie you're looking for, then you're probably looking for something else, so I'd recommend posting a new story-ID question of your own. If you were hoping for a response from Jaimie, bear in mind that they haven't been active on the site in over a year. That may be why _The Club_ was never confirmed to be the correct answer; that answer was posted about a year ago.

Comment: I believe we are looking for the same movie. I think there was some kind of pig mask or pig demon thing. When they get stuck inside, the gates were just gone and I think replaced by bushes that they couldn't get through. I was about 7 or 8 when I watched it which means it would've needed to be released before 1996.

Comment: @Adam - I believe the film the author of this question was looking for is _[The Club](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/260942/122024)_ (1994), as it perfectly matches their description. If that's not the film you're looking for, I recommend that you post your own story-ID question by clicking on the '[Ask Question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)' button at the top of the page. You're more likely to get the correct answer that way than by posting a comment in this thread.

Answer (score 7):

Having just watched a film called ***[The Club](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0109449/)*** (1994), I'm pretty sure it's the one you were looking for.

> Time stops at midnight at the Senior Prom for five students, one murderous counselor, and John. They must find the courage to face themselves or, when time starts again, they may find that they are joining John's Club. All you have to do is commit murder... or suicide.

The film begins with a high school's Senior Prom being held in a castle, replete with suits of armour and a guillotine in the basement. There are many people in attendance, mostly wearing medieval-themed costumes.

We get a few scenes introducing us to the main characters and establishing that some of them already have issues. For example, we see a girl breaking up with her boyfriend, who responds by becoming aggressive, as if he's about to hit her, before another student walks in on them, enabling the girl to flee the situation. The girl in this scene has curly hair and is wearing a black dress and a cloak, which fits the description of one of the characters mentioned in the question.

About 13 minutes into the film, the clock strikes midnight, and most of the people in the castle vanish, leaving behind six students. Two of them are girls, one being the girl in the black dress I already mentioned, and the other, a blonde girl in medieval garb. The four guys include the first girl's recently-dumped ex. The guys are mostly dressed in medieval garb too, except for a nerdy boy with long hair who's wearing a suit that looks a bit more modern. He could be the one you said was dressed like a '20s newspaper man. In fact, this boy mentions that he was the editor of the school paper last year, although I don't know if his outfit was meant to tie into that.

> [image: Image of four of the main characters from "The Club" (1994).]
>
> <sub>*The Club* (1994)</sub>

We see the kids wandering around the castle, trying to figure out what's going on. Around 23 minutes into the film, the girl wearing the black dress is in a restroom washing her hands and face, and when she looks up at her reflection in a mirror, she sees that one of her eyes is swollen shut, as if she's been punched. She runs back to the other students in a state of distress, but her face is fine; it was a hallucination.

> [image: Image of a girl looking at her reflection in a mirror from "The Club" (1994).]
>
> <sub>*The Club* (1994)</sub>

Around 35 minutes into the film, the boy with long hair and the two girls find a room containing stacks of books, apparently all different volumes of the same title. They start leafing through the pages of some of the books, and see photos of various people's faces, along with numbers indicating the years in which these people were born and died.

Around 43 minutes into the film, the boy with long hair is alone in the room with the books, when a doppelgänger of him walks up and starts taunting him. He tries to run away, but the doppelgänger keeps following him, and seemingly uses some form of telekinesis to place him in restraints. The doppelgänger then claims that the boy had previously intended to commit suicide, and starts doing things to injure himself, such as slitting his own wrists. Corresponding injuries appear on the boy as well, and he howls in pain.

> [image: Image of a boy being confronted by his doppelgänger from "The Club" (1994).]
>
> <sub>*The Club* (1994)</sub>

Then, about 49 minutes into the film, we see the same boy -- no longer in restraints, but with his eyes glazed over, as if in a trance -- placing his own head in the guillotine and pulling a rope to release the blade. Moments later, a picture of his face appears in one of the books, along with the years of his birth and death. The book then closes by itself, and we see that the title on the cover is *The Club: Suicides vol. 1993*. (There's no blood or gore in this scene, incidentally; the beheading is implied, rather than directly shown.)

> [image: Image of a photo of a boy's face in a book from "The Club" (1994).]
>
> [image: Image of the front cover of a book from "The Club" (1994).]
>
> <sub>*The Club* (1994)</sub>

I'll stop here, as I've matched all the details mentioned in the description at this point, so there's no need to spoil the plot any further. The film is available to watch for free on Tubi in the US and YouTube in Europe.

Answer (score 2):

Might this be ***[Night of the Demons](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093624/)*** (1988)...?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_of_the_Demons_(1988_film)):

> *Night of the Demons* is a 1988 American supernatural horror film directed by Kevin S. Tenney, written and produced by Joe Augustyn, and starring Amelia Kinkade, Cathy Podewell, Linnea Quigley, Hal Havins, and Alvin Alexis. The plot follows a group of high school students who throw a party inside an isolated funeral parlor. While attempting a séance, they accidentally release a demon locked in the crematorium that begins to possess them one by one.

Comment: @Jaimie - If anyone correctly identifies the movie you're looking for, please mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. Or if the only answers posted are incorrect, please indicate that with a comment so we know to keep looking. Thanks.

Comment: The movie is not "Night of the Demons". Your comment is incorrect.

Comment: @Jaimie - Fair enough. We'll keep looking! :-)